# Como achar um id específico dentro de uma lista?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Vou tentar resumir.

Tenho uma lista na qual tenho elementos com vários ids.

Eu gostaria de selecionar um elemento específico dentro dessa lista. Só que o valor que do ID que será procurado será preenchido dinamicamente.

Como faço pra selecionar esse elemento ?

**Segue um código de exemplo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Estou tentabdo selecionar dessa forma:**

```js
pagina_atual = parseInt($.parseJSON(data).paginaatual);
$('#pagina-atual').val(pagina_atual);

$("#ul-paginacao li a:contains('" + pagina_atual + "')").css("background", "red");
```

**Porém está acontecendo isso:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está selecionando todos os elementos que tenham id que contenham '1'. (Podendo ser 1, 144, 145, 194, etc ...)

**CÓDIGO DE CRIAÇÃO DOS BOTÕES**

```
<?php

  if($i == $paginaAtual || $i == ($paginaAtual-1) || $i == ($paginaAtual+1)){       
     $botoes .= "<li class='page-item'>";
     $botoes .= "<a class='btn btn-sm btn-primary botao-de-filtro-numerico' href='' id=b".$i.">".$i."</a>";
     $botoes .= "</li>";
  }
  
  
   //PARTE QUE envio o JSON do PHP para o retorno do AJAX
   $retorno = array();
   while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($operacao_consulta))
   {        
        
      $retorno[] = $linha;
                        
   } 
    
   $objeto = array(     
   'botoes' => $botoes,
   'dados' => $retorno,
   'paginaatual' => $pg_atual,
   'quantidadebotoes' => $totalDePaginas,
   'totalderegistros' => $totalDeRegistros
    );
        
    echo json_encode($objeto);


?>
```

**OBS: Essa variável $i é oriunda de um FOR do php**

**CÓDIGO JAVASCRIPT**

```js
//Trás o retorno do banco com todos os botões (<li><a></a></li>) que serão mostrados na paginação
paginacao += $.parseJSON(data).botoes;
//paginacao += "<li class='page-item'><a class='btn btn-sm bg-light text-primary border-primary' href=''>Próximo</a></li>";
$('#registros-atividades').html(atividades);

//Insere os botões na UL da paginação
$('#ul-paginacao').html(paginacao);

//Coloca no input hidden a página que está sendo mostrada na paginação
pagina_atual = parseInt($.parseJSON(data).paginaatual);
$('#pagina-atual').val(pagina_atual);


//Conta o número de botões que foi retornado no banco de dados. 
contador_de_botoes = parseInt($.parseJSON(data).quantidadebotoes);
//Coloca esse valor no input hidden
$('#quantos-botoes-tem-na-pagina').val(contador_de_botoes);

//Total de registros retornados
total_registros = parseInt($.parseJSON(data).totalderegistros);
$('#total-de-registros').html(total_registros);

//$("#ul-paginacao li a:contains('" + pagina_atual + "')").css("background","Indigo");
parametro_id = pagina_atual.toString();
$("#ul-paginacao li#" + parametro_id).css("background", "red");
```

Poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: Coloque o código HTML que você possui atualmente. Além disso, o valor dinâmico, seria por exemplo, um inteiro, como `1`?

Comment: O HTML é preenchido dinamicamente. Só existe um <ul> na parte HTML. O valor dinâmico é realmente um inteiro.

Comment: @Petherson da uma olhada na minha resposta ;) parece simples, mas caso n seja isso me avise

Comment: Repare isto na última linha: `$("#ul-paginacao li#" + parametro_id)`... irá buscar uma li que contenha o id da variável `parametro_id`. Se o id está na tag `a` dento da LI, o correto seria ter um espaço entre `li` e `#`, assim: `$("#ul-paginacao li #" + parametro_id)`... mas isso não faz sentido já que um id deve ser único, poderia fazer assim: `$("#" + parametro_id)`

Comment: Cara, deu certo aqui. As respostas tanto do SAM quanto a do Leonardo foram úteis pra mim. Agora não sei qual aceitar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como todo `id` é **único** ou seja, você só poderá ter um `id = "1"` na sua página, você poderia fazer assim(muito mais simples):

```
function SetBackgroundRed(id){
   $("#"+id).css("background", "red");
}

pagina_atual = parseInt($.parseJSON(data).paginaatual);
$('#pagina-atual').val(pagina_atual);
SetBackgroundRed(pagina_atual) //Pelo que vimos pagina_atual = id
```

Você seleciona o objeto a partir desse trecho `$("#"+id)`, coloquei numa `function` para você reutilizar em outros lugares.

Caso não seja esse o problema por favor me avise ;)

Comment: Não está dando certo. Esses botões não criados dinamicamente no php. Vou atualizar o post para vocês verem o código de como eu crio esses botões.